# Typing Callable in python to specific methods

Tags: python, typing, static-typing, mypy

I am trying to be very strict with my typing, and I encounter an issue when I want to type a Callable to only a few very specific methods!

I have a class:

```
class Complex:

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Complex()

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Complex()

    def __div__(self, other):
        return Complex()
```

In another file I want to write a method that takes in a Callable, but the argument to the method can ONLY be either the **add** function or the **sub** function. That means I want the linter to throw an error if I try to pass in **div** as a function to test_add_sub()

The code below doesn't seem to work :( The linter nor the compiler complains when I pass in the **div** function to test_add_sub! Nor can I write Complex.complex_func().

```
    add_sub_type = Complex.__add__ or Complex.__sub__
    add_sub_type2 = Callable[[Complex.__add__ or Complex.__sub__], None]


    def test_add_sub(complex_func: add_sub_type) -> None:
        print(complex_func)
        Complex.complex_func() <-- 'Class Complex has no complex_func member'
```

Thank you all very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`typing` can't do that. The static pseudo-type system doesn't allow you to define a type with an arbitrary set of members. (Also, `Complex.complex_func()` isn't how you'd call `complex_func` anyway.)

If you really, really want a static, type-based check for this, you could use an enum instead of the methods:

```
class ComplexAddSub(enum.Enum):
    add = Complex.__add__
    sub = Complex.__sub__

    def __call__(self, left: Complex, right: Complex):
        return self.value(left, right)

def whatever(func: ComplexAddSub):
    func(Complex(), Complex())

whatever(ComplexAddSub.add)
```

Comment: How about using a decorator to wrap up desired member functions? Is it detectable by **linter**?

Comment: @KaiserKatze: With the right decorator, probably, but you'd need to replace the methods with some other object type, which has its own messy consequences.

Comment: Could you please demonstrate how to detect class/instance function wrapped up by decorator with linter/compiler?

Answer (score 1):

## Runtime detection

```
def test_add_sub(complex_func):
    tester = {Complex.__addr__: False, Complex.__sub__: False}
    if (tester.get(complex_func, True)):
        raise RuntimeError('Invalid argument!')

    #complex_func(some_complex_object, another_complex_object)
```

Read more about **Instance methods** [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__func__#the-standard-type-hierarchy).

Comment: The question is looking for a static check, not a runtime check. Also, watch your spelling. It's `__func__` and `__add__`, not `__funct__` and `__addr__`.

Comment: @user2357112 Sorry about the spelling. But I see no explicit hint about asking for a static check in the body of the question. And in tag list there are both _typing_ and _static-typing_. I can hardly determine if OP wants no runtime check.

Comment: The question includes the line "That means I want the **linter** to throw an error if I try to pass in `__div__` as a function to test_add_sub()". Also, `mypy` is a static type checker, and the question is tagged both "mypy" and "static-typing". It's pretty clear they want a static check.

Comment: Seeing user2357112's answer, saying 'typing can't do that', this seems like the more elegant solution. Even though I was looking for static-typing. Oh well. Thank you!

Comment: @BjørnOlavJalborg: Clarification: do you want to pass `Complex.__add__` or `some_complex_object.__add__`? It's hard to tell from your question, since `Complex.complex_func()` isn't how you'd use either option. If you want `Complex.__add__`, then remove the `__func__`.

Comment: @BjørnOlavJalborg I would suggest you take a look at these two builtin classes: [complex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#complex) and [numbers.Complex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html#numbers.Complex)

Comment: @user2357112 You have a point, I should check both class function and instance function

Comment: @user2357112 I want to pass Complex.__add__. Just the function! I realize now Complex.complex_func() doesn't make much sense. Just calling complex_func() would make more sense, right?

Comment: @BjørnOlavJalborg: It'd be `complex_func(some_complex_object, another_complex_object)`.

Comment: @BjørnOlavJalborg If so you don't need `__func__`, I'm gonna update my code then.